# ListView : increase empty space when scroll bar end C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am new in C#. I have a problem with list view. I need to increase empty row when scroll bar ends.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by increasing empty row? Do you want to have an empty row at the end of list? You can add an Item with empty text and sub items with empty text. Also you can consider using a `DataGridView`.

Comment: Looks like __there is no empty row at the end__.  Note that as all rows have a height and you are free to set the __listview height__ to anything it is up to you to avoid extra pixels after the last row.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei , if i added empty subitems that makes problems , if add again subitems with value thats shows a gap

Comment: @ TaW , i need more empty row at scroll bar end , like  listview without value

Comment: @Jeen Maybe its better to share the reason behind this requirement, then perhaps you receive a different solution. Anyway, while I don't know why you need such empty space, for example you can put the `ListView` in an `AutoScroll Panel`, then set the height of your `ListView` to `(Count of Items + 5) * Height of  an Item`. This makes a taller list view.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei , i dont want to increase height of list view , suppose if i need to add a right click menu on empty row space that would be difficult , also if i add drag n drop on empty row space same issues comes , hope u understand my issue , drag n drop perform on selected items not on empty space ,because empty space is too small when scroll bar comes

Comment: @Jeen Unfortunately I couldn't understand the requirement. Can you describe more or share a picture from what you need?

Comment: @Jeen Also if you read my previous comment, I think it will provide what you need. It makes the list view taller but since it is in a auto scroll panel, every thing is ok.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei Pic 1 http://postimg.org/image/6ib3htg6f/
Pic 2 http://postimg.org/image/81plgq8ul/